# How to map SQL Server view with one to many related data to ViewModel class with ICollection in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, viewmodel, one-to-many, sql-view

I want to create a view model that looks something like the following where `CustomerInfo` is the view model that contains a collection of orders and each order contains a collection of order details.

```cs
 public class CustomerInfo
 {
     public CustomerInfo()
     {
         OrderInfo = new HashSet<OrderInfo>();
     }

     public int Custid { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Region { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<OrderInfo> OrderInfo { get; set; }
 }

 public class OrderInfo
 {
     public OrderInfo()
     {
         OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrdDetails>():
     }

     public int OrderId { get; set; }
     public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

     public ICollection<OrdDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
 }

 public class OrdDetails
 {
     public int Orderid { get; set; }
     public int Productid { get; set; }
     public decimal Unitprice { get; set; }
     public short Qty { get; set; }
     public decimal Discount { get; set; }

     public virtual OrderInfo Order { get; set; }
 }
```

A SQL Server database contains a view that stores data from the three related tables: `customer`, `order` and `orderdetails` using joins.

Is it possible for me to map that T-SQL view to the `CustomerInfo` view model class using a keyless entity type or DBQuery?

I would rather not use DBQuery if possible because it is no longer supported in the latest .NET Core version, and I do not want the application to break if we decide to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy job.

Assume there is an entity class, declared for a database record has compound `Customer`, `Order`, and `OrdDetail` relational primary columns,

```cs
public partial class CustomerOrderDetail_Entity : ICustomerInfo, IOrderInfo, IOrdDetails
{
    public int Custid { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int Orderid { get; set; }
    public int Productid { get; set; }
    public decimal Unitprice { get; set; }
    public short Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
}
```

In order to make it easy and simple in beginning, try create a view and query every columns in those three tables,

```sql
SELECT  
  dbo.Customer.Custid, dbo.Customer.City, dbo.Customer.Region, 
  dbo.[Order].OrderId, dbo.[Order].OrderDate, 
  dbo.OrdDetail.Productid, dbo.OrdDetail.Qty, dbo.OrdDetail.Discount, dbo.OrdDetail.Unitprice
FROM  dbo.Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.[Order] ON dbo.Customer.Custid = dbo.[Order].Custid LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.OrdDetail ON dbo.[Order].OrderId = dbo.OrdDetail.Orderid
```

Then, create a data access, ORM function to meet your needs,

```cs
virtual CustomerInfo GetCustomerOrderDetail(int custId, string connectionStringName = null)
{
    IEnumerable<CustomerOrderDetail_Entity> entities;
    using (var conn = DbConnectionFactory.CreateDbConnection(connectionStringName ?? DefaultConnectionName))
    {
        conn.Open();
        entities = conn.Query<CustomerOrderDetail_Entity>(@"
SELECT *
FROM uv_CustomerOrderDetails
where CustId = @CustId
", new { CustId = custId });
    }

    return entities?.ConvertTo<CustomerInfo>(); 
}
```

No matter how complicated your data structure is, it's ORM mapping's stuff. Since every thing is in-memory now, probably not difficult converting or mapping them into `OrdDetails`, `OrderInfo`, and `CustomerInfo` classes by using `legacy for-loop, LINQ, or 3rd-party mapper package`.

---

However, the first view should not created for a general purpose, it's better for a query which NOT called very frequently, such as data analysis, otherwise it continuously wastes large traffic to retrieve a bigger size dataset with redudant columns, such as `Customer.City`, `Customer.Region`, they are all the same for a customer, and `[Order].OrderDate` for the same order as well.

Another relatively optimized view than eariler, like this,

```sql
SELECT  
  dbo.Customer.Custid, 
  dbo.[Order].OrderId, 
  dbo.OrdDetail.Productid
FROM  dbo.Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.[Order] ON dbo.Customer.Custid = dbo.[Order].Custid LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.OrdDetail ON dbo.[Order].OrderId = dbo.OrdDetail.Orderid
```

Though saved large of data size now, **CustomerOrderDetail_Entity** data are not fully filled any longer. Instead, need many supporting methods to make it complete. Here's an example how I use second view, then convert dataset into `CustomerInfo`, `OrderInfo`, `OrdDetails` respectively.

```cs
virtual CustomerInfo GetCustomerOrderDetail(int custId, string connectionStringName = null)
{
    var customerInfo = DBHelper.CachedCustomerInfo(custId);
    var orders = entities
        ?.Where(o => o.Custid == custId)
        ?.GroupBy(o => o.Custid)
        ?.SelectMany(group => group);
    if (orders?.Count() > 0 != true)
    {
        return customerInfo;
    }

    customerInfo.OrderInfo = new List<OrderInfo>();

    // fill orders
    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        var orderId = order.OrderId;
        if (orderId <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var orderInfo = DBHelper.CachedOrderInfo(orderId);
        customerInfo.OrderInfo.Add(orderInfo);

        // fill order details
        var orderDetails = DBHelper.CachedOrderDetails(orderId);
        if (orderDetails?.Count() > 0 != true)
        {
            continue;
        }

        orderInfo.OrderDetails = orderDetails.LinkOrder(orderInfo).ToList();
    }

    return customerInfo;
}

// query CustomerInfo by PK:CustId, and Cache CRUD
virtual CustomerInfo CachedCustomerInfo(int custId);

// query OrderInfo by PK:OrderId, and Cache CRUD
virtual OrderInfo CachedOrderInfo(int orderId);

// query OrdDetails list by FK:OrderId, and Cache CRUD
virtual IEnumerable<OrdDetails> CachedOrderDetails(int orderId);

// make OrdDetails.Order property link to its owner Order
virtual IEnumerable<OrdDetails> LinkOrder(this IEnumerable<OrdDetails> details, OrderInfo order);
```

Frankly, as a system's complexity grows, there will be much more stuff to do. My opinion would be `don't reinvent the wheel` unless your system is keep that small.